# Remove div on clicking anywhere

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to remove an appended div, I've tried `.empty()` and `contents().remove();`

I've commented out the removed code, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2Aw23/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4KZf/)

It will add the div when the button is clicked, but then remove it when anything else is clicked.  But note that other code may also specify that clicks on other parts of the page should stop propagation, so if that is the case, clicking those elements also will not remove the div.

Comment: thanks, i think without (evt.propogation) it was removing the appended div immediately, however in my case i want the div to remove even if its clicked on other clickable elements, is there a way for this? or do i have to add remove evt on those.

Comment: My example will remove the new div when anything is clicked except for the div that adds it in the first place.  But if your page has code that specifically stops event propagation for an element, then no, it won't remove the div when clicked, and there's nothing you can do about that.  That's the point of stopping propagation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {  
    $('#tip').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the same functionality as Tadej mentioned but use it on the container div, and your button, you need to put it outside of that container and use absolute position to make it go to the right place
i am sure there is a jquery way around this but the css way works too